# Invalid index 8, size is 8 in android

Tags: android

i m facing problem. as i enter 8 values in array and i can confirm that size of array is 8 by using array.size() but when i call following loop it can gave me outofbound exception. i m traversing 4 values in one loop cycle.

```
    for (int pos=0; pos < array.size(); pos += 4)
    {
         id = db.insert(array.get(pos), array.get(pos+1), array.get(pos+2));

         id_array.add(String.valueOf(id));
         id_array.add(array.get(pos+=3));
    }
```

please help

Comment: I believe you are trying to do `for (int pos=0; pos + 3 < array.size(); pos += 4)`

Answer (score 3):

Your array is of size 8, so it is indexed from 0 to 7. In your loop, when pos is 0, the `pos+=3` statement makes it 3, then you increment it by 4, which makes it 7 and when you call `pos+1` you get the exception.

I suppose this is a typo and:

```
id_array.add(array.get(pos+=3));
```

should be

```
id_array.add(array.get(pos+3));
```

Also, your real termination condition is that `pos+3` must be a valid position in your array so you should use:

```
for (int pos = 0; pos + 3 < array.size(); pos += 4)
```

Comment: His for loop is also incorrect it should read `for (int pos=0; pos + 3 < array.size(); pos += 4)`. Unless its a valid fact that it will be multiples of 4? Better safe than sorry

Comment: @Doomsknight Yes agreed. If the array size is 9, he will have issues too. Edited accordingly.

Comment: thanx alot assylias. its my mistake i did'nt notice '=' sign in (pos+3), now it works well. thanx

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to acces the Array at Position 8.
If the size is 8 that means the array is filled from 0 to 7.